# Notification to another email account

Tags: support, notifications, email

I have registered on SO with a yahoo account, but i want to be notified at another gmail account. I did what comment said. It seemed to work for TAG subscription.

**UPDATE:**
I have subscribed to the answers of the questions I have asked, but didn't receive any email regarding questions. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: @you: i am suffering from this problem. What should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your email in your profile without affecting your OpenID, which is what you use to log in.

*1. Click on the username at the top of the page on the site where you want to change your email to go to your profile.*

*2. Click the **edit** link.*

[image: profile page with link to edit profile]

*3. Change your email.*

[image: edit profile screen]

*4. Click **Save Profile** at the bottom of the page.*

Comment: My account is created login with yahoo option. So I guess there's no change email option. Is there some way so I can transfer my account to GMail?

Comment: @Riyad I don't quite understand. Is there no box in which you can change your email?

Comment: @YOU: yeah, this is the problem I am suffering. I have 2 open id accounts, i want to delete one and merge this with another one

Comment: @you: did it. thanks. really appreciate it